# Obtain data from a colour scaled map

Tags: python, matlab

i have a map that shows magnetic field strength and it uses a color scale so that when the colour is red on the map this means that the magnitude is approaching positive maximum and if its green then its close to 0 and when it gets to blue its approaching negative infinity, and i am looking for a way so that whenever i move the cursor on the map i would know the value of the magnetic field at that point based on the colour

i tried converting the RGB scale to numerical data but that was stupid because i keep getting 3 different values for each point

Comment: forgot to mention that the map is basically a image from a scientific paper

Comment: I assume, the map was originally created by applying a certain colormap to the mentioned magnetic field strength data. Now, you have a three-channel ("color") image of the final map, and what you would need is some kind of reconstruction of the used colormap from the pixel values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825867/11089932) outlines some possibilities and also some code doing this using Python and OpenCV. Apart from that: Obviously, the easiest way would be to ask the authors of the scientific paper to provide the original data.